# SQLCMD running as builtin Admin Group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlcmd

How to run SQLCMD with builtin Administrator Group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run CommandPrompt (or PowerShell) as Administrator (so that you have elevated permissions). Then use sqlcmd with the -E flag, so that it uses your Windows login (using sa these days isn't recommended).

Answer (score 0):

[RUNAS](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true)